# Hard Drive doesn't appear in Windows 8.1 setup

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I have both x86 and x64 disc for 8.1 full and I had to remove my hard drive to run the setup. If I don't I get a message that no boot able devices exist. The setup starts when the hard drive isn't in and so I put it in after setup has opened but it doesn't show in the list where I want to install windows.

Comment: Why would you have to remove the drive to install Windows?

Comment: @canadmos honestly I don't know

Comment: Well, what happens when you leave the drive connected and boot from the install disk?

Comment: if istart the pc with the hdd connected it gives me the no bootable device but without the cd boots

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to edit the boot order to list the CD/DVD drive first or invoke the boot menu so that you can select the CD/DVD drive to boot from... after you put the HDD back in.

Comment: I can't access it

Comment: I first started with windows 8 and replaced with linux mint. now Linux mint is gone

Comment: Can you access the BIOS? Normally done by pressing the "Del" or "F2" key on start-up.

Comment: no I cannot access bios

Comment: If you can't even access the BIOS, I'd say you require on-site help. I honestly doubt trouble shooting will help here. As said above, you will need to gain access to your BIOS to verify the boot order. After that, make sure that your Windows 8 installation disk is bootable (try it in another computer and try to boot from it...but don't actually do anything). Also, where did Mint vanish to? Is your hard drive even connected and powered on? Its all in the details....